# Escape entity in xml files

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am convert xml to xml file, I try to convert text as for source. I am currently using xml::Twig and I need output without any change in xml.

I Tried:

xml:

```
<book>
<book-meta>
<book-id pub-id-type="doi">98568</book-id>
<copyright-statement>Copyright &#x00A9; 1999 Relati</copyright-statement>
<imprint-text type="PublisherInfo">This edition published in the Taylor &#x0026; 2002.</imprint-text>
</book-meta>
</book>
```

Script:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
use XML::Xpath;
open(my $output , '>', "Output.xml") || die "can't open the Output $!\n";
my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {
keep_atts_order => 1,
keep_encoding => 1,
},
pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$xml_twig_content->parsefile('sample.xml');
$xml_twig_content->print($output);
```

output:

```
<book>
<book-meta>
<book-id pub-id-type="doi">98568</book-id>
<copyright-statement>Copyright © 1999 Relati</copyright-statement>
<imprint-text type="PublisherInfo">This edition published in the Taylor &amp; 2002.</imprint-text>
</book-meta>
</book>
```

I need output:

```
<book>
<book-meta>
<book-id pub-id-type="doi">98568</book-id>
<copyright-statement>Copyright &#x00A9; 1999 Relati</copyright-statement>
<imprint-text type="PublisherInfo">This edition published in the Taylor &#x0026; 2002.</imprint-text>
</book-meta>
</book>
```

How can i need as source without any changes.

Comment: why do you include XML::XPath here? It's not needed by your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your `new` statement: `keep_encoding` and `keep_atts_order` parameters are declared as `twig_handlers`. I don't think that's what you want, since the only thing this does is to die as soon as an element named `keep_atts_order` or `keep_encoding` is found in the XML.

I think this is more like what you had in mind:

```
my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new( keep_atts_order => 1,
                                       keep_encoding => 1,
                                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                                     );
```